# python how to know if subprocess is waiting for input

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm running subprocess from my app (GUI). sometimes, the subprocess will ask for inputs from user.
I would like to know how can I check if the subprocess is waiting for the input, and if it's waiting, I want to open a window asking for this input, and provide the value to the subprocess.
I can handle opening the dialog window, but I want to know how to check if it's waiting and how to provide the input to the subprocess..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your subprocess outputs some prompt for user to input data, like:

> Please enter your name:

you can use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html) library to wait for this prompt and then feed your data into it.

You can do this with a code that looks like:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('my-process -v')
child.expect('Please enter your name:')
child.sendline(user_name)
```

pexpect also supports regexs and timeouts for advanced scenarios.